# Simple conceptual question about probability

Tags: statistics

Consider $N$ molecules. The probability that any of those $N$ molecules has an exact value of speed is zero because there is a finite amount of molecules and an infinite amount of possible speeds so that when we "zoom in" the probability approaches zero.

However, we get around this problem by dividing the "field" of infinite number of speeds into finite number of intervals and instead of asking the question "what number of molecules has a speed $v$" we ask the question "what number of molecules has any speed in the interval $v$ to $v+dv$.

But, $dv$ is infinitely small, so how is it possible that for an exact value of speed the probability is zero, but for an infinitely small speed interval it is nonzero.

I'm sorry if this is trivial, but it's really bugging me in trying to understand this basic statistics concept.

Comment: Usually, the idea behind Statistical Thermodynamics is to replace the continuous case with some sort of discrete approximation...eventually hoping to pass to the continuous limit.  Of course there is no problem saying that some observation has a non-zero probability of being in some range.

Comment: I understand all of that, but what exactly is the difference between a fixed value and an infinitesimal interval around that value?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by an infinitesimal interval.  Usually such things really mean a finite interval like $[x,x+\Delta x]$ and using the term infinitesimal indicates that you intend to pass to the limit $\Delta x\to 0$.

Comment: Exactly, an infinitesimal interval would be $[x, x+dx]$ and my question is why is the probability of $[x, x+dx]$ (when we approach $x$ to an infinitely small distance $dx$) nonzero when the probability of $x$ itself is zero?

Comment: What does "infinitely small distance " mean?  Can you define that precisely?

Comment: It would be $\lim_{\to 0} \Delta x$.

Comment: That's just $0$.

Comment: Physicists tend to blur the distinction between small, but non-zero, increments and the limits as those increments go to $0$.  This simplifies the writing (skipping steps tends to do that) but it's not rigorous and it's easy to get confused.  Take the argument you are reading, rewrite it using actual increments, and then pass to the relevant limits.